# how to pass selected day value as parameter to another activity?

Tags: android

how to pass selected button value as a parameter to another activity??? below is my code and this is screen shot http://imgur.com/YkbE8AS   my code display calendar in horizontally suppose user select any day in week like wednesday  its not fix value is dynamic value so how do i pass selected day value with month and year to another activity as a parameter????in my cdoe 7 buttons which text are dynamic i want to when user click any day that value with current month and year pass as  parameter to another activity suppose abc.java when button mybutton willl click??

```
           public class HoyahCalendar extends Activity {
public static int mYear;
public static int currentIndex = -1;
public static int mMonth;
public static int mDay;
public static String[][] a = new String[6][7];
String  January="January";
String  February="February";
String  March="March";
String  April="April";
String  May="May";
String  June="June";
String  Jully="Jully";
String  August="August";
String  September="September";
String  October="October";
String  November="November";
String  December="December";
String  Monthname;

 TextView date_today;
 ImageView last_month;
 ImageView next_month;

 ImageView last_week;
 ImageView next_week;


 Button e00;
 Button e01;
 Button e02;
 Button e03;
 Button e04;
 Button e05;
 Button e06;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    getIntent().setAction("Already created");


    date_today = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.date_today);
    last_month = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.last_month);
    next_month = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.next_month);
    last_week = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.last_week);
    next_week = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.next_week);



    e00 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.e00);
    e01 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.e01);
    e02 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.e02);
    e03 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.e03);
    e04 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.e04);
    e05 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.e05);
    e06 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.e06);

    Calendar mCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    mYear = mCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    mMonth = mCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1;
    mDay = mCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);



    last_month.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if (mMonth == 1) {
                mYear -= 1;
                mMonth = 12;
                new ShowCalendar(mYear, mMonth);
                showOnScreen();
            } else {
                mMonth -= 1;
                new ShowCalendar(mYear, mMonth);
                showOnScreen();
            }

        }
    });

    next_month.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if (mMonth == 12) {
                mYear += 1;
                mMonth = 1;
                new ShowCalendar(mYear, mMonth);
                showOnScreen();
            } else {
                mMonth += 1;
                new ShowCalendar(mYear, mMonth);
                showOnScreen();
            }

        }
    });

    last_week.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (mMonth == 1) {
                mYear -= 1;
                mMonth = 12;
                new ShowCalendar(mYear, mMonth, mDay, "last");
                showOnScreen();
            } else {
                // mMonth -= 1;
                new ShowCalendar(mYear, mMonth, mDay, "last");
                showOnScreen();
            }
        }
    });

    next_week.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if (mMonth == 12) {
                mYear += 1;
                mMonth = 1;
                new ShowCalendar(mYear, mMonth, mDay, "next");
                showOnScreen();
            } else {
                if (HoyahCalendar.currentIndex == 4) {
                    HoyahCalendar.currentIndex = 4;
                    // mMonth += 1;
                }

                new ShowCalendar(mYear, mMonth, mDay, "next");
                showOnScreen();
            }

        }
    });

    new ShowCalendar(mYear, mMonth);
    showOnScreen();

  }

       public void showOnScreen() {

    if (mMonth ==1) 
    {
        Monthname="January";
        }
    else 
        if (mMonth ==2) { 
            Monthname="February";
            }

        else
    if (mMonth ==3) { Monthname="March";}
    else 
        if (mMonth ==4) { Monthname="April";    }

        else
    if (mMonth ==5) { Monthname="May";}
    else 
        if (mMonth ==6) { Monthname="June"; }
        else
    if (mMonth ==7) { Monthname="July";}
    else 
        if (mMonth ==8) { Monthname="August";   }
        else
    if (mMonth ==9) { Monthname="September";}
    else 
        if (mMonth ==10)    { Monthname="October";  }
    if (mMonth ==11)    { Monthname="November";}
    else 
        if (mMonth ==12)    { Monthname="December"; }


    date_today.setText(  Monthname + "  " +mYear);
    e00.setText("" + a[0][0]);


    if(e00.getText().toString().equals(String.valueOf(mDay)))



    {e00.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFBBFF"));
    Toast.makeText(this, "Button1 text equals!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }

    else
    {
        e00.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
    }


    e01.setText("" + a[0][1]);

    if(e01.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase (String.valueOf(mDay)))


    {
        e01.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFBBFF"));

    Toast.makeText(this, "Button2 text equals!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
    else
    {
        e01.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
    }

    e02.setText("" + a[0][2]);
    if(e02.getText().toString().equals(String.valueOf(mDay)))

    {e02.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFBBFF"));
    Toast.makeText(this, "Button3 text equals!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
    else
    {
        e02.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
    }
    e03.setText("" + a[0][3]);
    if(Integer.parseInt(e03.getText().toString()) == mDay)
    {e03.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFBBFF"));
    Toast.makeText(this, "Button4 text equals!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }


    else
    {
        e03.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
    }


    e04.setText("" + a[0][4]);
    if(e04.getText().toString().equals(String.valueOf(mDay)))
    {e04.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFBBFF"));
    Toast.makeText(this, "Button5 text equals!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }

    else
    {
        e04.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
    }


    e05.setText("" + a[0][5]);
    if(e05.getText().toString().equals(String.valueOf(mDay)))
    {e05.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFBBFF"));
    Toast.makeText(this, "Button6 text equals!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }

    else
    {
        e05.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
    }

    e06.setText("" + a[0][6]);
    if(e06.getText().toString().equals(String.valueOf(mDay)))
    {e06.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFBBFF"));
    Toast.makeText(this, "Button7 text equals!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }


    else
    {
        e06.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
    }


}


 public void onRestart() {
     super.onRestart();
         Intent intent = getIntent();
         finish();
         startActivity(intent); 
         }
```

Comment: Pass the day as an int extra when starting the intent for the new activity.

Comment: You can use Intent().putExtra(name, value) for passing data between activities

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well, u said you know how to pass bundle with intent, why dont u create a variable in your class that is initialised with current date.

```
variable value = current date;
```

onClick of any button you change the variables value to the one you want to send to your activity

```
onClick(){
value = value you want to send
}
```

and send that parameter in bundle to the intent.

Thus your requirement :

```
 " if user not click any value then go current date value as parameter else what ever button eser click that day value will go as parameter"
```

will work, if anything is not clicked the variable `value` is already initlialized with current date thus will be send to the activity and you can process it the way you want.

Plz ignore the syntax, its jst pseudo code.

Comment: i know how to pass but i dont know what button user click there is 7 button horizontally how do i know which button user click? and its value wilbe pass as parameter??

Comment: firstly, there is no OnClicklistener shown in your code for button click\, if you could post the code then can help also if you are using a common click listener to all your buttons then you can differentiate which button was clicked from their ids, use a switch with all ids of the button as cases and compare with view.getID() and update the value variable

Comment: i do not want to add Intent for 7 times for each button i want single intent used to pass pressed button value as parameter

Comment: yes, implement onCLicklistener in your class and in onClick() function use a switch statement with all id's of the buttons and also set this listener to all buttons. you can do it in a single function jst differentiate between the buttons on their ids using switch(view.getID())

Comment: this will help check the second answer.     http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3795439/one-onclickhandler-for-multiple-buttons

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

To pass information from one activity to another when you start the new one you do the following:

```
Intent top = new Intent(Main.this, New.class);
Bundle b = new Bundle();
b.putString("key1", "value1");
b.putString("key2", "value2");
b.putString("key3", "value3");
top.putExtras(b);
startActivity(top);
```

Then in the newly started activity, in the onCreate() put the following:

```
Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
String one = b.get("key1");
String two =b.get("key2");
String three =b.get("key3");
```

This will get the values from the previous activity by using the key you provided.

Comment: iknow how to pass value as parameter but in my code how do i get selected button value????? i want if user not click any value then go current date value as parameter else what ever button eser click that day value will go as parameter how do i do that????

Comment: You can create a Class variable that stores the clicked button day. so you can pass it to intent.

Comment: create any global variable and on click button set value to variable like BtnClicked = 2 or BtnClicked = btn.tag,. and when you are sending to another activity pass that variable.

Answer (score 0):

make use of a `function` and a variable `dtSelect`
set `dtSelect = default` at the beginning
and if user selects any button set that particular value to dtSelect

once u have a value stored in `dtSelect` pass it to a `function` (as `i.putstring()`) to carry out the task u desire based on the value you have in the variable...

Comment: i dont believe in writing exact code with all syntax...(which i hate to memorize).. but having pseudo code i think we can write the syntax using android docs...one more hint could be using switch statement...

Comment: im not genrate intent function  on each button ijust want when user click any date that day  value will save   when user click a new button like mybutton its strat Intent and pass selected button value as parameter

Comment: i mean  how tostore selected day value and pass as parameter to another activity when mybutton will click???

Comment: ok one basic question i have is ARE YOU ABLE TO STORE THE SELECTED DATE INTO A VARIABLE.....