# I have 34 buttons on my android application. Is there any way to avoid writing onclicklistener for each of them?

Tags: java, android

Can i write some code so that instead of writing a separate onClick listener i can group them all in single piece of code? Presently i have this. Now how can i avoid writing onclicklistener method for each.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    DecimalFormat currencyFormatter = (DecimalFormat) NumberFormat.getInstance();
    char decimalSeparator = currencyFormatter.getDecimalFormatSymbols().getDecimalSeparator();
    mDecimalSeparator = Character.toString(decimalSeparator);

    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    mInputStack = new Stack<String>();
    mOperationStack = new Stack<String>();

    inputText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.InputText);
    inputText.setText("0");
    resultText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ResultText);
    resultText.setText("");

One = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
Two = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
Three = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
Four = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button4);
Five = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button5);
Six = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button6);
Seven = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button7);
Eight = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button8);
Nine = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button9);
Zero = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button0);
Add = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonAdd);
Subtract = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonSubtract);
Multiply = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonMultiply);
Divide = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonDivide);
Delete = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonDel);
Period = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonPeriod);
Equal = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonEqual);
Sin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonSin);
Cos = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonCos);
Tan = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonTan);
Cosec = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonCosec);
Sec = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonSec);
Cot = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonCot);
Sinh = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonSinh);
Cosh = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonCosh);
Tanh = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonTanh);
Factorial = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonFactorial);
Log = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonLog10);
Ln = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonLoge);
Reciprocal = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonReciprocal);
Square = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonSquare);
SquareRoot = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonSquareRoot);
Power = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonPower);
Percent = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonPercent);


One.setOnClickListener(this);
Two.setOnClickListener(this);
Three.setOnClickListener(this);
Four.setOnClickListener(this);
Five.setOnClickListener(this);
Six.setOnClickListener(this);
Seven.setOnClickListener(this);
Eight.setOnClickListener(this);
Nine.setOnClickListener(this);
Zero.setOnClickListener(this);
Add.setOnClickListener(this);
Subtract.setOnClickListener(this);
Divide.setOnClickListener(this);
Multiply.setOnClickListener(this);
Equal.setOnClickListener(this);
Delete.setOnClickListener(this);
Period.setOnClickListener(this);
Sin.setOnClickListener(this);
Cos.setOnClickListener(this);
Tan.setOnClickListener(this);
Cot.setOnClickListener(this);
Sec.setOnClickListener(this);
Cosec.setOnClickListener(this);
Sinh.setOnClickListener(this);
Cosh.setOnClickListener(this);
Tanh.setOnClickListener(this);
Percent.setOnClickListener(this);
Reciprocal.setOnClickListener(this);
Log.setOnClickListener(this);
Ln.setOnClickListener(this);
Power.setOnClickListener(this);
Square.setOnClickListener(this);
SquareRoot.setOnClickListener(this);
Factorial.setOnClickListener(this);
Sign.setOnClickListener(this);
```

Comment: Use switch case onClick method in which you can trigger your event using IDs of your different Buttons.

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3795439/one-onclickhandler-for-multiple-buttons

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set an android:click property in the xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:orientation="vertical"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent"
 >
<TextView  
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:text="@string/hello"
 />
<Button android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:text="Go!"
 android:onClick="goButtonClicked" android:id="@+id/goButton"></Button>
</LinearLayout>
```

SimplestButtonActivity.java

```
package com.botbook.simplestbutton;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class SimplestButtonActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }

    public void goButtonClicked(View v) {
        tToast("Go button clicked!");
    }

    private void tToast(String s) {
        Context context = getApplicationContext();
        int duration = Toast.LENGTH_LONG;
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, s, duration);
        toast.show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set an android:click property in the xml.  This will allow you to decide what function to call when the button is clicked in the xml.  The function must take the same parameters as the normal onClick function and must be part of your activity, but can be named anything you want-  Like onePressed, twoPressed, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.button1:
        // do stuff;
        break;
    case R.id.button2:
           // do stuff;
        break;
    case R.id.button3:
        // do stuff;
        break;

        //....add here add buttons 

    default:
        break;
    }
}
```