# One click listener for all views in a hierarchy?

Tags: android

Is there a way to set one click listener on all views in a hierarchy in one line? I believe we have to do something like the following:

```
<LinearLayout id="@+id/parent">
    <TextView id="@+id/item1" />
    <TextView id="@+id/item2" />
    <TextView id="@+id/item3" />
</LinearLayout>

OnClickListener listener = ...;

View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.the_above_layout);
view.setOnClickListener(listener);
view.findViewById(R.id.item1).setOnClickListener(listener);
view.findViewById(R.id.item2).setOnClickListener(listener);
view.findViewById(R.id.item3).setOnClickListener(listener);
...
```

But that's really a lot of code for a big view hierarchy. I could make a recursive function to do it, but is there something already available by android that does this for us?

Thanks

Comment: Not one line but if you want to keep your Java code less messy, you can set them in xml as shown here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18319711/android-eclipse-which-is-the-best-way-to-add-a-button/18319759#18319759

Answer (score 2):

Android just implements the OnClickListener for you when you define the android:onClick="someMethod" attribute in xml.

```
<LinearLayout id="@+id/parent">
    <TextView id="@+id/item1" android:onClick="myFancyMethod" />
    <TextView id="@+id/item2" android:onClick="myFancyMethod" />
    <TextView id="@+id/item3" android:onClick="myFancyMethod" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Then in your Activity just define a method like this.

```
public void myFancyMethod(View v) {
// does something very interesting
}
```

That is probably the fastest way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

that is nice example i think so bcz i m also finding shortest way to clic[i refer this site for click listner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3795439/one-onclickhandler-for-multiple-buttons)

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {

Button button1, button2, button3;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
    super.onCreate();

    ...

    button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    button3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);

    button1.setOnClickListener(this);
    button2.setOnClickListener(this);
    button3.setOnClickListener(this);
    }
    @Override
     public void onClick(View v) {
     switch(v.getId()) {
       case R.id.button1:
       // do stuff;
       break;
       case R.id.button2:
       // do stuff;
       break;
   ...
 }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is the way add this line in your xml-

```
<TextView id="@+id/item1" 
android:onClick="myMethod"
/>
```

And make sure you write this method in your class in which xml is used

```
public void myMethod(View v){
 //content goes here
}
```

this will trigger your own methods