# Opening activity from fragment force close error

Tags: java, android-fragments

So today I created tab view bar and fragments and added some image buttons to one of the fragments.
When I add `android:onClick="name"`on the button code and write Intent in .java file, it gives me force close error when I click on that button.

Here's my code:

fragment.xml

```
<ImageButton
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/btnProgramiPL5x5"
            android:minHeight="80dp"
            android:background="@mipmap/btn_programi_pl_5x5"
            android:onClick="ProgramiPowerlifting5x5"/>
```

fragment.java

```
   package hr.app.liftme.liftmehr;


import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.ContactsContract;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageButton;


/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 */
public class FragmentPowerlifting extends Fragment {



    public FragmentPowerlifting() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }




    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_powerlifting, container, false);


    }
```

ProgramiPowerlifting5x5.java

```
    package hr.app.liftme.liftmehr;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;

public class ProgramiPowerlifting5x5 extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_programi_powerlifting5x5);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
    }

}
```

Error i get is this:

```
01-26 23:00:44.766 14491-14491/hr.app.liftme.liftmehr E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                        Process: hr.app.liftme.liftmehr, PID: 14491
                                                                        java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find method ProgramiPowerlifting5x5(View) in a parent or ancestor Context for android:onClick attribute defined on view class android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageButton with id 'btnProgramiPL5x5'
                                                                            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.resolveMethod(AppCompatViewInflater.java:307)
                                                                            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:266)
                                                                            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4856)
                                                                            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19956)
                                                                            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:211)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5389)
                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1020)
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:815)
```

I don't know what is the problem, when I link two activities I use `this, name.class`, but that didn't worked in this case so i used `getActivity` and it still does not work.

I would really appreciate help!

Thanks!

Comment: Can you show all the constructors of ProgramiPowerlifting5x5 ?

Comment: Android Studio is an IDE. Who cares what text editor you use? It's irrelevangt for the question. Don't you understand the difference?

Comment: That's not a constructor, it returns a void and it is probably not even in the class

Comment: Along with what Gavriel said, I would strongly advise against naming methods the same as the class name. It is very confusing for people who read the code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Button Onclick](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10231309/android-button-onclick)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is:

> Could not find method ProgramiPowerlifting5x5(View) **in a parent or ancestor Context**

The `onClick` attribute refers to the parent `Context` (as parent `Activity`) so the fragment's method is not triggered and not handled by this attribute.
You have to handle the click in the Activity:

```
public class ProgramiPowerlifting5x5 extends AppCompatActivity {
    ...
    // change the method's name to avoid confusion with constuctor
    public void ProgramiPowerLifting(View view){
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, ProgramiPowerlifting5x5.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Or trigger the same method into your fragment:

```
public class ProgramiPowerlifting5x5 extends AppCompatActivity {
    private ProgramPowerFragment fragment;
    ...
    public void ProgramiPowerLifting(View view){
        fragment.ProgramiPowerLifting(view);
    }
}
```

[This great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6271637/2668136) uses **a callback interface** which, personally, I'd suggest. Or you can easily forget the `onClick` xml attribute and do it dynamically with `setOnClickListener()`.
So, let's try the easy way:

```
public class FragmentPowerlifting extends Fragment {

    public FragmentPowerlifting() { }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // store the layout in a view variable
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_powerlifting, container, false);
        // use this view ("v") to retrieve elements on the layout by its id
        ImageButton imgButton = (ImageButton) v.findViewById(R.id.btnProgramiPL5x5);
        // set a listener to the button
        imgButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                // open a new activity when onClick is triggered
                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), ProgramiPowerLiftingActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        }
        // return the inflated view to display it
        return v;
   }
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but none of that helped. Still getting the same error

Comment: Sorry to ear that @DaxHR. But even by testing the other answers in the link posted?

Comment: No. Don't know why, why isn't the procedure same as when starting new activity from activity?
Is maybe onClick  responisble for error? Should I use onClickListener?

Comment: @DaxHR this shouldn't be the starting activity part where the problem is. Try with onClickListener yes, without xml attribute.

Comment: I'm getting errors when trying to add onClickListener in Fragment.java.. it does not recognize fingViewById

Comment: @DaxHR I hope it's a typo because it's fin**D**ViewById(), but in fragment you need to attach the view inflated in onCreateView like `View v = inflater.inflate...; Button btn = (Button) v.findViewById();`

Comment: I'm sorry, that was a typo. Would you like me to post whole .java files so you can correct them?

Comment: I uploaded all the text so if you would like to help that would be cool!

Comment: And me my answer @DaxHR, hope you'll get it. Don't forget to delete the button's onClick attribute if you are using the onClickListener dynamically

Comment: Thank you! 
Another problem. It wont recognize my .class on new Intent get activity. No typos though

Comment: NEVER MIND! You solved it! You are a God!!! Thank you so much man, I really apreciate it!

Comment: Glad to read that @DaxHR! You could [accept my answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/253846) to inform that your problem no longer exists. Happy coding!

Comment: Did that!
Another question, I have multiple image buttons in that fragment, when I want to set onClickListener to another one, do I have to create another method or?

Comment: Thank you @DaxHR. Yes, you have to. But to be more convenient, you can implement the listener to the fragment, set the event on the context (fragment class) `setOnClickListener(this)` and handle all clicks in `onClick` method. Described in [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25905313/2668136) and [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3795472/2668136).

Comment: That didn't work, had set fragment class to abstract and then it wouldn't run because fragment can't be abstract. Weird
But I've found a solution. Thank you so much for your time and help!